# MyPy doesn't raise type mismatches between different files

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8, mypy

In a directory with the following structure:

```
src/
  my_module/
    foo.py
    bar.py
```

I run MyPy using `mypy src/mymodule`.

If there is the following in a single file (e.g. `foo.py`):

```py
# foo.py
def hey(whatever: str) -> int:
    return 234

hey(22)
```

Then MyPy will complain, as it should.

```sh
$ mypy src/my_module
src/my_module/foo.py:4: error: Argument 1 to "hey" has incompatible type "int"; expected "str"
```

However, if one file calls a function from another file:

```py
# foo.py
def hey(whatever: str) -> int:
    return 234

# bar.py
from foo import hey
hey(22)
```

Then MyPy finds no error:

```sh
$ mypy src/mymodule
Success: no issues found in 2 source files
```

How to make sure that MyPy checks type consistency between different files?

Comment: With mypy 0.770 I got: 
`my_module/bar.py:3: error: Argument 1 to "hey" has incompatible type "int"; expected "str"`

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` file? `mypy` may be resolving `foo` / `hey` as `Any` otherwise.